# How to make button highlighted or pale in java swing properly?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm using Swing with default UI (without any special skins).

How to make some buttons/textfields more bright or more pale? It means the user is expected/not expected(although not completely disabled) to press the button.

Example: user had changed a field - "save" button becomes more bright (for example, green). Status is "compilation failed" - "execute" button is pale (although user can still execute previous version of something). User filled in "password" field - he expected to fill in "password confirmation" - so it becomes bright.

- I have: {normal, disabled, invisible}
- I want: {bright, normal, pale, disabled, invisibe}.

How to make it properly, without hacking with drawing things, with separation of content and presentation? I want it to look well even if user overridden colour settings in the system. Should I use some other toolkit?

I expect something like I set hints for the given control, and then skin read hints and applies additional look and feel options (such as brighter background) without me dealing with concrete colours. May be one skin will use other background and some other skin will use other font for this effect. Like in enabled/disabled case, but more flexible.

Comment: I know about setEnabled, but it can only make it pale and disables it. I want "soft disable" + the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use setBackground() to change the color to match the component's status.  Maybe even create a Custom Component that has a method to change the status and it knowns which color matches that status.

Comment: You can pull the component's current color and call brighter() or darker(), however I was thinking you would just define your own 5 colors and store them in constants somewhere for use by the component.

Comment: What if user change system skin to some other one? As I think, good application should not rely on what colours do it's UI controls have unless it manages skins itself.

Comment: Then specify a specific look and feel.  I suggest Nimbus.  (If you are going to start to mess with the colors of buttons, then it makes sense to specify a look and feel.

Comment: So, it's not possible to have more flavours than just "enabled" and "disabled" without completely taking control on look and feel, right? I expected something like I set hints for the given control, and then skin read hints and applies additional look and feel options (such as brighter background). Like in enabled/disabled case, but more flexible.

Comment: @Vi, you can have more flavours, they might not look right. The difference with enabled and disabled is that each look and feel defines looks for those states.  Any new states would not be supported specifically by other look and feels.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I see the value in what you're trying to achieve from the examples that you've provided. Is it possible that users could get confused about how the application works if you give them functionality that differs from their expected user experience?

If the user hasn't yet changed a field, the save button could be completely disabled. What's the value in being able to save if there have been no changes made. Alternatively, if you still dead set on making this distinction, can you do it in another way? Perhaps a visual queue, an icon next to the field that's changed, cell highlighting, or a * appended to the end of the text on the window name to show that there are unsaved changes in a window, perhaps?

From a purely user experience perspective, I don't think you want to go messing with the way people expect applications to behave unless you have a *really* good reason!

Comment: So it's better not to introduce more states other than enabled and disabled? How about "adviced" state? Means user should press this button, but there are cases when this is not required.

Comment: For your "advice" state, you could place a small icon next to the button of choice, or modify the border of the button.